# Merge 64 bit tags

Tags: discussion, support, retag-request

I've just noticed there are currently 128 `64-bit` tags and 89 `x64` tags. While that's a fair few of each I really think they should be merged before it gets much messier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree but which tags are appropriate.  Are all 64-bit questions x86 or do we have some ia64 in there?  Should things about ia64 and x64 be in the same tag even though they are completely different?

Personally I would prefer [32-bit], and [64-bit] to be eliminated and we go with [x86], [x64], and [ia64] for the most part.  But there probably are some generic 64 bit questions that are not tied to any specific cpu architecture.

In a related cleanup I wonder if we should change all the [windows-release-{arch}] replaced with two tags like [windows-release] [arch].

- 32-bit× 36
- 32bit-64bit× 31
- windows7-32× 4
- 32bit-64bit× 31
- <s>64bit× 6</s>
- 64-bit× 129
- amd64× 15
- ia64× 2
- tru64× 4
- windows-7-64× 34
- windows-7-x64× 5
- windows-vista-64× 20
- x64× 80
- x86-64× 4

Comment: All of the 64bit questions were clear, and that one was easy.  Merged & synonymed to 64-bit.  I agree on the OS+arch items, but I'll save some fun for another day. ;)

Comment: I prefer [32-bit] and [64-bit], because they can be used for either CPU or software questions, whereas [x86] and [x64] are applicable to CPU questions only and are technically inaccurate anyway.

Comment: @John Gardeniers You'd better add this comment as an answer.. I'd rather up-vote that :)

Comment: the second part of you answer can be a separate question, here people won't be able to check it & up-vote it separately :)

Answer (score 0):

Why merge?  tags are for searching so clearly there are some folks that say 64 bit and some that say x64.  If anything I'd say ensure that all are crosstagged with both.  However for tags like windows-7-64 vs windows-7-x64 I'd certainly say pick one and merge them.

Comment: Three problems come immediately to mind. 1 - x64 is technically incorrect anyway, as it was fabricated to appear as a continuation of x32, which is also invalid, etc. and should be actively discouraged. 2 - The number of tags is growing to the point where they are becoming useless for searching simply because it's hard to know which of several possibilities might apply. 3 - "Crosstagging" is hard or useless when there is only a 5 tag limit. It would be far better to use appropriate tags, rather than multiple ones saying the same thing.